# Allow Laravel to respond to 403 instead of nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I am trying to have Laravel respond a custom 403 error rather than display the default nginx forbidden page.

I have custom handlers for most of my exception types in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and they are working just fine, except for 403. I added the following code to the `Handler.php file` within the `render` function to handle 403:

```
if($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode() == 403){
        return response("403 Forbidden error response");
    }
```

but I still just see the default nginx forbidden page if I lets say navigate to http://myapp.com/images/

At this point I am fairly certain this is an nginx config I may be missing, but am not 100% sure what and after searching the web can't seem to find the solution.

Thanks

Comment: What is preventing user to access `/images`?If is the server block at nginx configuration, you won't be able to change the response on the laravel, since it will block before Laravel being called.

Comment: Please [edit] to include your nginx config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the advice and reviews everyone, I have been able to find and fix what was causing the issue. As Elias Soares mentioned above in comment, the issue was obviously happening before Laravel was even reached. I went into my nginx config file and noticed the following line:

```
error_page 404 /index.php;
```

and since Laravel was indeed correctly handling 404 errors, I simply added the exact same thing for 403:

```
error_page 403 /index.php;
```

and now Laravel is handling any 403 errors the way I wanted it to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to do anything special.

Just create 403.blade.php under `resources/views/errors/` and you should be good.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#custom-http-error-pages