# Avoid Nginx showing Bad Gateway for Laravel's 500 errors in local dev

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

When developing locally on this project, I'm having issues where when my PHP Laravel application throws a `500` error I see a `502 Bag Gateway` instead of an error page rendered by PHP.  I do have the following env vars set:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

In prod, I see Laravel resolve the `500.blade.php` error page as expected, but locally nothing is shown.

For example, a bad method call can trigger this:

> 022/09/04 22:19:45 [error] 867#867: *103 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: [2022-09-04 22:19:45] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method....

I haven't been able to identify any configuration setting that I can tweak within nginx that'll enable it to show errors rather than a Bad Gateway.

Any suggestions on what configuration might need to be changed here?

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
    server_name  app;

    access_log off;
    error_log /dev/stdout;

    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # this causes issues with Docker
    sendfile off;

    location = favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    # look for local files on the container before sending the request to fpm
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # nothing local, let fpm handle it
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass            localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
        include                 fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param           REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
        fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param           QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
        fastcgi_param           CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
        fastcgi_param           CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;
        # Httpoxy exploit (https://httpoxy.org/) fix
        fastcgi_param           HTTP_PROXY "";

        # allow larger POSTS for handling oauth tokens
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
   }

    # Deny .htaccess file access
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: [502 Bad Gateway for Laravel 5.4 with nginx and php7.0-fpm in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907811/502-bad-gateway-for-laravel-5-4-with-nginx-and-php7-0-fpm-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa For me, this only happens when php-fpm returns a `500` error code.  And actually in production, a `500` error code produces an error page as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I created my `nginx` **virtual-host/code-block** by this way and it's working for me,  I'm using `8000 port` but you can use `80 port`. However, it preferable if we don't map port `80` with any of single project in local development because mostly we are working on multiple projects so you should need to enable different `ports` of every `project`.

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    root /var/www/html/<project-path>/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: Ports actually don't matter here, because everything's running in Docker. 
 Unfortunately adding `error_page 500 /index.php;` to nginx within my `server` block of the nginx config (See my config above) doesn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the behavior is caused by the php configuration, not by nginx.
Try setting

```ini
display_errors = on;
```

Unless otherwise instructed nginx passes the exact error code it receives.

There is one other alternative I can think of, perhaps the script is timing out on error for some reason causing the 502.

Comment: Adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` followed by `phpinfo();` shows the setting is correctly being set to `on`, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual header response you getting from your request?

I'd suggest you do some test and try to isolate the issue if this is a problem with nginx config, php config or your laravel environment and error handling instead.

you can create a `test.php` file in your public folder

i.e.

```
<?php

http_response_code(500);
TEST;
```

now if you open `site/test.php` are you getting 500 error or 502 error? and is the error displaying something like undefine TEST constant.

or how about you edit `public/index.php` and just break the code like adding `.` somewhere, are you also getting 502 response in your laravel app?

502 errors usually happens when you set nginx as a proxy or does not get a valid response, you can enable [debug mode](https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) to see what happens with your request.

also post your nginx.conf

and maybe try adding `fastcgi_intercept_errors off;` on your php or main location block

**EDIT**

Another possible cause of this is the upstream too big and more than your nginx config `buffer_size`

You can try increasing the buffer size,

add inside `http` block in `whatever-environment-you-have/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

then on your `~php` block add the following

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

if still doesnt work try increasing all to `4096k`

Comment: Adding `http_response_code(500);` to the top of my `public/index.php` I see a 500  in the browser.  I added the `fastcgi_intercept_errors ` directive within `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {` and no luck, still showing 502.  My nginx config is posted above in the question.

Comment: I edited my answer, it might that error your app producing is too large and nginx can't handle. 
Since your set-up is fine with simple 500 error

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply route the error codes to your index.php file so Laravel can deal with them.

This has been covered in multiple other questions on StackOverflow. Here's one -

[Allow Laravel to respond to 403 instead of nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648976/allow-laravel-to-respond-to-403-instead-of-nginx)

Just use 500 (502) instead of 403.

Comment: My expectation is that https://github.com/spatie/laravel-ignition (which is a dependency of my project) would take over and display a helpful error message since I'm in a dev environment.

Comment: @Ben - if the error never reaches Laravel, it can't be intercepted by Ignition. You can ofcourse look at [the docs](https://flareapp.io/docs/ignition-for-laravel/installation) to confirm that your installation is done correctly. But it definitely looks like an nginx configuration issue. Another thing to look at is Laravel's own nginx sample config [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#nginx) (the try_files line looks different from yours - maybe that's all it is)